# Setting up a personal loan, how do I report to CRA?

Tags: canada, personal-loan, canada-revenue-agency

I am about to make a simple loan to a family member. I have a contract written up, and a payment schedule that we will both sign as well, along with a witness.

While the interest rate I am charging is fairly low (2%), I know that I need to report the income on my taxes.

What information do I need to collect from the person I am loaning the money to, and what all do I report to CRA for my taxes?

Comment: Why would a CRA be involved in your taxes?

Comment: @Norm CRA = Canada Revenue Agency, who we send our tax paperwork to

Comment: Ahhh... When I see CRA, I think Credit Reporting Agency! I missed the Canadian thing entirely! Now I feel like a big dope.

Comment: @Norm T'is alright! Canada isn't the center of the universe either :)